# JQuery: how to append one element of a variable inside an element of another variable?

Tags: jquery, variables, append, children

I have used `.load()` to get two elements from a php file and have stored each in its respective variable:

```
var $one=("<div>");
$one.load("first-url form");  //the element is a form

var $two=("<div>");
$one.load("second-url #button"); //the element is a button with id #button
```

Using JQuery I would like to insert the `#button` of `$two` inside the `<form>` of `$one`.

Both consist of a `<div>` inside which reside the the actual elements.

I believe this could be attainable using a combination of `.children()` and `.append()` but I just can't figure it out.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the point of what you are doing. You want to load a single button from external document. What is so special about the button? Why not just make a new button (http://pastebin.com/GRNQiukD)? || I am also thinking, why doesn't the form just contain that button to begin with?

Comment: Of course one button would not be an issue. I need to .load() various parts of various url's, and I want to link different forms with different buttons—each residing in a different url. I don't want to rewrite the code for each button(the buttons are not simple submit buttons and each has different css.
All I want to know is how to target a specific element in the html saved in a variable. Let's say I need to add a class to the second <p> element inside the html saved in variable $foo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this would be possible with `.load()`, I feel that `$.get()` might be a bit easier.

```
var content = $('#content');

// Get the first file...
$.get( "file1.html", function( data ) {

    // Append "file1.html" data to #content
    $(data).appendTo( content );

    // Get the second file...
    $.get( "file2.html", function( data ) {

        // Find #button element from "file2.html" 
        // data and append it to #content form.
        $(data).filter('#button').appendTo( content.find('form') );

    });

});
```